# why java doesn't support pointers?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't we use pointers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924236/why-cant-we-use-pointers-in-java)

I want to know are there any pointer concepts in java?

I know that there is no explicit declaration of pointers but implcitly pointer concept is implemented.Why there is no pointer in java

Comment: why there is no pizza in McDonald?

Comment: What about a pointer do you want? Define a pointer.

Answer (score 10):

You have to distinguish between several uses of pointers:

- **Memory access via pointer arithmetic** - this is fundamentally unsafe. Java has a robust security model and disallows pointer arithmetic for this reason. It would be impossible for the JVM to ensure that code containing pointer arithmetic is safe without expensive runtime checks. You don't need pointer arithmetic unless you are writing extremely low level code (in which case you should probably be using assembler or C/C++ instead)
- **Array access via pointer offsets** - Java does this via indexed array access so you don't need pointers. A big advantage of Java's indexed array access is that it detects and disallows out of bounds array access, which can be a major source of bugs. This is generally worth paying the price of a tiny bit of runtime overhead.
- **References to objects** - Java has this, it just doesn't call them pointers. Any normal object reference works as one of these. When you do `String s="Hello";` you get what is effectively a pointer to a string object.
- **Passing argument by reference**, i.e. passing a reference which allows you to change the value of a variable in the caller's scope - Java doesn't have this, but it's a pretty rare use case and can easily be done in other ways. This is in general equivalent to changing a field in an object scope that both the caller and callee can see.
- **Manual memory management** - you can use pointers to manually control and allocate blocks of memory. This is useful for some applications (games, device drivers) but for general purpose OOP programming it is simply not worth the effort. Java instead provides very good automatic garbage collection which takes care of memory management for you. This is an extremely good thing: for many people who had previously been forced to deal with manual memory management in Pascal/C/C++ this was one of the biggest advantages of Java when it launched.

So overall Java doesn't have pointers (in the C/C++ sense) because it doesn't need them for general purpose OOP programming. Furthermore, adding pointers to Java would undermine security and robustness and make the language more complex.

Answer (score 3):

If you asking why there is no direct access to memory locations, that is to guarantee memory access safety. No more segfaults and buffer overruns, no matter how incompetent the programmer (and managed memory is also extremely convenient for a programmer, no matter how competent).

If you are asking why no passing-by-reference, or function pointers, then there are workarounds to achieve the same effect with other constructs.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to look at the proportion of questions (on SO, for example) that people ask about C pointers causing SIGSEGV, or Objective-C pointers causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS :-)

Java *has* pointers, it just doesn't call them pointers (other than in the suspiciously-named `NullPointerException`). It provides pretty much the same facility but in a safer manner, such as preventing you from setting them to arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: are there any pointer concepts in java?

A: Yes.  They're called "references".

> Q: but implcitly pointer concept is implemented ... here is no explicit declaration of pointers

A: Correct.

"Safety" is one reason commonly given.

But a more important reason is "level of abstraction".  If Java "hides" implementation details (like how an array is laid out in memory, for example), it's free to "optimize" things (like give you a standard way to query the array length - something C/C++ cannot directly do).  It's free to implement "garbage collection".  The door is suddenly wide open to these - and many more - opportunities the language and runtime are free to take advantage of.

Just FYI, here's a contrary view:

- http://warp.povusers.org/grrr/java.html

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a simple question with a simple answer but here's the gist of it.

Java doesn't give the programmer direct access to memory, therefore no pointers no malloc no free no realloc etc. This is done for safety reasons, it protects the programmer from tampering with things (in Java's mind at least) they shouldn't.

Comment: *"... here is the jest of it"* - is that a spelling error or a clever meta-joke? (Hint: lookup "jest" and "jist" in the dictionary.)

Comment: actually i wrote jist and firefox indicated it was spelled wrong.

Comment: My mistake.  The correct spelling is "gist".

Comment: hence why firefox was yelling at me. Fixed.

Comment: Firefox yellowing?  Shirley you jist!

Comment: Please don't call me Shirley...