# Why java is not using pointers

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480783/pointers-in-java)

Why java is not using pointer though C# and other language using it explicitly?

As i think due to some safety reason it does't allow user to access its memory allocations.

update: i want to know java is known as a very safe language, so lack of pointer does have any relevance with its robustness or safety.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924236/why-cant-we-use-pointers-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Why should it? Which advantage do you think Java could gain by using pointers? Pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Discussing the philosophy of language design is off-topic here.  If you have a specific problem caused by the lack of pointers and are looking for a work-around, ask away.

Comment: I think it could be different mean of question by previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pointers is considered unsafe and mistakes can even lead to system instability.
In C# we do not use pointers. You can do that using unsafe block, but you only do it for code that needs to be optimized for speed.  I think in java it should be also possible, although I have never programmed in java, so someone should confirm/deny in a comment.

Comment: No pointers in Java. Every variable is a reference (except primitive types) and behaves like a pointer, but there is no pointer arithmetic or stuff like that.

Comment: No pointers but there is still `NullPointerException` :-) Should probably have been `NullReferenceException` instead...