# What are classes, references, and objects?

Tags: java, oop, class, object, reference

I've been programming Java for 2 years now, and I have encountered a problem where I couldn't understand and differentiate class, reference, and an object.

I am not sure if a class or reference are the same, though I have an idea of what an object is.

Can someone differentiate in a complete manner what classes, references, and objects are?

All I know is that a class is more like a template for an object (blueprint to a house where the class is the blueprint and the house is an object).

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html.

Comment: If you have C experience (or some procedural language) you can think of objects as structs with methods. So *class* would be de struct declaration (with associated methods), *objects* would be the concrete structs given (this struct is one object, that struct is another object) and *references* are pointers to that structs.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

If you like housing metaphors:

- a **class** is like the blueprint for a house. Using this blueprint, you can build as many houses as you like.
- each house you build (or instantiate, in OO lingo) is an **object**, also known as an **instance**.
- each house also has an address, of course. If you want to tell someone where the house is, you give them a card with the address written on it. That card is the object's **reference**.
- If you want to visit the house, you look at the address written on the card. This is called **dereferencing**.

You can copy that reference as much as you like, but there's just one house -- you're just copying the card that has the address on it, not the house itself.

In Java, you can not access objects directly, you can only use references. Java does not copy or assign objects to each other. But you can copy and assign references to variables so they refer to the same object. Java methods are always pass-by-value, but the value could be an object's reference. So, if I have:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();     // 1
callBar(myFoo);            // 2
myFoo.doSomething()        // 4

void callBar(Foo foo) {
    foo = new Foo();       // 3
}
```

Then let's see what's happening.

1. Several things are happening in line 1. `new Foo()` tells the JVM to build a new house using the `Foo` blueprint. The JVM does so, and returns a reference to the house. You then copy this reference to `myFoo`. This is basically like asking a contractor to build you a house. He does, then tells you the house's address; you write this address down.
2. In line 2, you give this address to another method, `callBar`. Let's jump to that method next.
3. Here, we have a reference `Foo foo`. Java is pass-by-value, so the `foo` in `callBar` is a *copy* of the `myFoo` reference. Think of it like giving `callBar` its very own card with the house's address on it. What does `callBar` do with this card? It asks for a new house to be built, and then uses the card you gave it to write that new house's address. Note that `callBar` now can't get to the first house (the one we built in line 1), but that house is unchanged by the fact that a card that used to have its address on it, now has some other house's address on it.
4. Back in the first method, we dereference `myFoo` to call a method on it (`doSomething()`). This is like looking at the card, going to the house whose address is on the card, and then doing something in that house. Note that our card with `myFoo`'s address is unchanged by the `callBar` method -- remember, we gave `callBar` a *copy* of our reference.

The whole sequence would be something like:

1. Ask JVM to build a house. It does, and gives us the address. We copy this address to a card named `myFoo`.
2. We invoke `callBar`. Before we do, we copy the address written on `myfoo` to a new card, which we give to `callBar`. It calls that card `foo`.
3. `callBar` asks the JVM for another house. It creates it, and returns the new house's address. `callBar` copies this address to the card we gave it.
4. Back in the first method, we look at our original, unchanged card; go to the house whose address is on our card; and do something there.

Comment: last question so basically. myFoo is where you store the reference of a said object?

Comment: @user962206 You're welcome. :) As for your question, basically: In colloquial lingo, myFoo *is* the reference, which is where you store the *address* of an object. (You never actually see what that address is in Java, btw -- you just know it's there, and that the JVM knows how to look at it.) If you read the JLS though, they'll say that myFoo is a variable of reference type, and that it stores the reference to the object.

Comment: does this concept also apply for C#? except about the (JLS) ?

Comment: @user962206 I'm not sure, never got really into C#. But I believe C# is a superset of C++, in which references are something else entirely. Java references are closer to C++ pointers. So, I don't know what C# calls its version of Java references.

Comment: do you know any place where there is an OOP concepts guide like (Classes,references, and objects) regardless of programming language? just OOP concepts in general ? but if you could explain them to me regardless of the language please do :)

Comment: @user962206 don't know, sorry. Maybe wikipedia?

Comment: What's the difference between reference and address? It feels you are using them somehow interchangeably. From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629758/689991) answer, 'reference to pointer' is used to dereference a variable. But what is a reference? A number? or a pointer pointing towards a pointer?

Comment: @iamcreasy They're very similar. An address is the place in the JVM (that is, in memory) where the object lives. A reference is a variable that points to this address. The analogy would be like asking what's the difference between an integer and an `int` -- an integer (or address) is a thing you want stored, and an `int` (or reference) is the thing that stores it.

Comment: I'm from a .net background, but am a little confused: the foo variable is passed to the Callbar method. In other words, my friend Callbar builds a new house at the address of the existing myFoo house. Doesn't he demolish the myFoo house to build the new Foo house? In other words, isn't the myFoo variable now referring to the new house that has been built by CallBar, rather than the old house it originally referred to?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Callbar wasn't given a house, it was given a card on which was written the address of a house. So, it didn't build a new house at that address -- it built a new house, and then wrote the address of that house on the card. That means that Callbar can't find the old house any more -- but nobody else is affected. The old house is still there, and anyone who had other cards with the old house's address can still find it.

Comment: @yshavit thank you for your clarification. I am following you 100% till you say this - then i get confused: Call bar can't find the old house anymore. agreed. "But nobody else is affected"? Would not the old house address cards now point to the callbar house instead? I"ll check this by code and get back to you with an answer because it is puzzling to me.

Comment: @yshavit you are 100% correct. i cannot believe i had misinterpreted the fundamentals like that.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, Java methods are always pass-by-value (object reference). So when callBar(myFoo); invoked only value (reference) is being passed and "foo"'s scope is only within callBar. And foo is getting new Foo() only. So foo is referencing new one - I guess I am right.

Answer (score 13):

When you code, you build an

> Instance (occurrence, copy)

of an

> Object

of a said

> Class

and keep a

> reference

to it, so you can call its methods.

Also, some [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) basics: [Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_science%29), [Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29), [Instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29), and [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: what does it mean when you "keep" a reference? is it like the implementation of that object? or the object is the implementation itself?

Comment: @user962206 A reference is nothing more than 'pointers' to where said object is, in-memory. One could say that you write the 'implementation' in the Class file, not sure that's what you mean?

Comment: That's what I mean, but if you could, can you explain more details to me about reference? I do get the object and class but not the reference

Comment: Okay thanks I finally get it now :)! Car myCar = new Car() myCare is   a reference right?

Comment: @user962206 Exactly! It is merely the address of the `Car` object you created on your machine's memory, so you can call its methods!

Comment: Thank you, one last thing. are instance and Objects the same?

Comment: @user962206 Nope: you always have an instance (or an occurrence, or a copy) of your object. Do also notice Java has a class called Object, which is the parent class in the hierarchy for all other classes written.

Comment: @Marcelo Slight nitpick: the reference isn't the address of the `Car` object, it's a place where you can store a copy of the address. If you modify the reference, it doesn't change the `Car`'s address -- just means you're now pointing to a different object (or `null`, which is no address).

Answer (score 9):

In the book "Thinking in Java" from Bruce Eckel it has been described perfectly:

"You might imagine a television (the object) and a remote control (the reference). As long as you’re holding this reference, you have a connection to the television, but when someone says, “Change the channel” or “Lower the volume,” what you’re manipulating is the reference, which in turn modifies the object. If you want to move around the room and still control the television, you take the remote/reference with you, not the television.

Also, the remote control can stand on its own, with no television. That is, just because you have a reference doesn't mean there’s necessarily an object connected to it. So if you want to hold a word or sentence, you create a String reference:

```
String s;
```

But here you’ve created only the reference, not an object. If you decided to send a message to s at this point, you’ll get an error because `s` isn’t actually attached to anything (there’s no television). A safer practice, then, is always to initialize a reference when you create it:

```
String s = "asdf";
```

However, this uses a special Java feature: Strings can be initialized with quoted text. Normally, you must use a more general type of initialization for objects.

When you create a reference, you want to connect it with a new object. You do so, in general, with the new operator. The keyword new says, “Make me a new one of these objects.” So in the preceding example, you can say:

```
String s = new String("asdf");
```

Not only does this mean “Make me a new String,” but it also gives information about how to make the String by supplying an initial character string.
Of course, Java comes with a plethora of ready-made types in addition to String. What’s more important is that you can create your own types. In fact, creating new types is the fundamental activity in Java programming."

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you write there two lines of code:

```
Engine app1 = new Engine(); //LINE 1

Engine app2  = app1; //LINE 2
```

In line 1, Engine is a **class**, its a blue-print basically.

new Engine() is the **instance** that is made on the heap.

You are refering that **instance** by using app1 and app2 in your code.

So app1 and app2 are the **references**.

Comment: if you mean instance, you mean object?

Comment: So app2 does not contain a copy of the engine created on line 1, it holds a copy of the reference that points to the engine.

Comment: Also a Null Pointer Exception is thrown when the reference to the engine returns null or does not point to anything.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object, what happens behind the scene is that a piece of memory is reserved for containing that object. This could be anywhere in the great big memory landscape; it's up to the operating system and the compiler, and you don't really have any control or knowledge of where it ends up.

Ask yourself, then, how do you use that object if you don't know where in memory it is? How can you read a value from it if you don't know where that value is stored? This is what references do for you. They are a way of keeping in touch with the object. It's a little string attached to the balloon that is a reference.

You use the reference to say that "I want to touch *this* object now!", or "I want to read a value from *this* object!".

Answer (score 2):

========= Class and Object ===========

Class => ex: Person (More like imagination)

Object => ex: John, Mike (Real person)

=========== Reference ============

ex:

**Television tv1;** - (Television is a class, tv1 is a remote controller without Television)

**Television tv2 = new Television();** - (Now tv2 remote controller has a Television)

**tv1 = tv2;** - (Now tv1 and tv2 can control same Television)

**Television tv3 = new Television();** - (tv3 is a new remote controller with new Television)

Answer (score 2):

**Class:** 
Structure or BluePrint

**Object:** 
Physical Manifestation

**Reference:** 
Address of Object

Answer (score 1):

Class is a template, you are right. It is some knowledge about data structure. Object is that structure instance in memory. Reference is a memory address of that instance.

If by `Object` you meant the java identifier, then `Object` is the basic class for all complex Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is the run time representation of the `Class`definition. And the **name with which you use the object** is called the `reference` (as it references the actual object location in memory )

example

```
MyClass ref = new MyClass();
```

Here, **MyClass** is (contains) the **class** definition.

**new MyClass()** creates an **object** for this class (done only during execution, hence runtime representsion)

**ref** is the name you use to work on the class object, is the **reference**.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Class : Used to define a real life entity into a programming environment.***

Any real life entity having at least one `property` and a corresponding `behaviour` can be considered as a class. Lets take an example of a **Car**, it is having a property `accelerator` which helps the car to move and to control its speed. The corresponding behaviour is `acceleration`, which is directly proportional to the push applied to the accelerator.

```
class Car {
    private String tier;
    private String tierFriction;
    private double weight;
    private double gasFedToEngine;
}
```

The above class shows some properties of a Car, on which its acceleration depends. Behaviour (`method in the class`) always depends on the property(s) (`global attribute(s) of the class`). Now if you want more details you can define `Tier` as another entity, then the definition will look like

```
class Tier {
    private String tierMaterial;
    private String tierFriction;
    private double weight;
    private double tierDiameter;
}

class Car {
    private Tier tier;  // getting all properties of Tier here itself
    private double weight;
    private double gasFedToEngine;
}
```

> ***Object : Used to define various flavours of an Entity and to perform data manipulations on them separately.***

Now we have defined an entity to our program, say we are having a showroom of used cars, having cars of different companies. So each car becomes an `object` of our entity. Objects can be Audi, Nissan, Ferrari etc. So after opening the showroom we add cars to it like this

```
static List<Car> showroomCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
public boolean addCarToShowroom() {
    Car carNissan = new Car();  // always creates a new objects and allocates some memory in heap
    carNissan.setName("Nissan");
    carNissan.setColor(RED);
    carNissan.setWeight(300);
    showroomCars.add(carNissan);

    Car carAudi = new Car();
    carAudi.setName("Audi");
    carAudi.setColor(BLACK);
    carAudi.setWeight(270);
    showroomCars.add(carAudi);
}
```

So now two new cars are added to the Showroom, one of Nissan and another one of Audi, each having their own specific attribute values.

`Class` only gives definition, manipulation is done on `Object`, for doing manipulation on any Class, object should be created. Every time an object is created to a class all its non-satic(instance) variables will load into memory with their respective default values.

> ***Reference : Used to address an object***

When we say `Car carAudi = new Car();` we define a new object to Car and a memory location is assigned for that object. The reference variable `carAudi` holds the memory address of that object. Object is never accessed directly by user, neither its memory location. That's where reference variable has significance, its stores the `hexadecimal` format of memory location. If we want to do modifications on an object do with the help of reference not directly.

***An object can have any number of reference, but a reference can point only to one object at a time.***

```
class Car {
    void test() {
        Car car1 = new Car();  // (1)
        Car car2 = new Car();  // (2)
        car2 = car1;
        /** 
         Says that car2 should point to where car1 points, so now both points to first object of Car
         But for this car2 has to loose its current object-(2), making it an Abandoned object (An object with no active reference from the stack).
        **/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In Real world, Object is a material thing that can be seen and touched in this universe.
- In Programming, Objects are same but those are stored or trapped inside a memory like when any object is being created. it will create in the RAM(Memory). So, As a human we will not be able to see it or touch it but it do exist in the memory somewhere.
- So, we don't care about how system is creating or destroying objects, rather we will see how to handle it using programming.
- In order to create an object, Programming language provide's us syntax format's which we can use handle these objects.
- Now, How you will define what object you want to create like if you want to create a customize new car then you have to provide your requirements to the manufacturer right?.
- Same way in programming, class is used. The class is a blueprint which will define how object should look like/what all data it will store and what all operation it will do. It doesn't exist in the memory and just used to define the requirements for creating an object.

Let's take an example of student:

```
//We have a Student class. Below are some attributes which we will use:
    class Student
    {
        string Name;
        int Age;
        string Address;
    }
```

Now, Above Student doesn't really exist. This is only a blue print of how student will be. If we need to create a student then we call it creating a object and below is the format to create one student.

```
Student student=new Student();
```

Now, 1 student object has been created in the memory which can be used to set any name/age/address and get the same information as shown below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.Name = "Vivek";
            student.Age = 24;
            student.Address = "Address";
            Console.Write("Student Name is " + student.Name + " whose age is " + student.Age + " and he/she stays at " + student.Address);
        }
```

Now, Assume you want to provide some work to Student, How will you do it?

```
//By writing a function/method and write the code which student should handle as below:
    class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;
        public string Address;

        public void Run()
        {
            //Write some code
        }

        public void Walk()
        {
            //Write some code
        }
    }
```

Above one is just an example as student will not run in the memory, So, Code which you have to write is C# code only or whatever programming language which you are using to write code. Like do some operation with C#.

Now, I would like to highlight that:

- if you see in the real world. Student does not only contain Name/Address/Age but student also have other attributes like Mother Name/Father Name/Passport etc. In addition to normal attributes, We can also add body parts like Brain/Heart/Legs etc.
- So, Class Student can be more complex if you add all attributes to it.

Example: Your customize car will not customize all parts of your car. You have to use exisiting parts like wheels/tier/Air conditioner etc. So, Classes can use exisiting classes/struct/methods/fields etc. in order to achieve the requirement. As you can see below that class is using other classes/struct/methods/fields etc. in order to achieve the requirements:

```
        //String is also class which represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units
        public string Name;

        //Integer is a struct which represents a 32-bit signed integer
        public int Age;

        //String is also class which represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units
        public string Address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Java is associated with class objects and classes, including attributes and methods. Ex:  a car is an object in real life. The car has attributes, such as weight and color, and methods, such as drive and brake. A Class is like an object constructor or a "blueprint" for creating objects.

A reference is an address that indicates where an object's variables and methods are stored. You aren't actually using objects when you assign an object to a variable or pass an object to a method as an argument.