# Basics about Java memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I read that [Java is passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-is-a-class-reference-and-an-object) . So lets say we have this code and say that the `HashMap somehashMap` has a longer life time than `foo` . So foo is not allowed to be garbage collected even though it has done its work simply because we put foo inside the Map and then forgot to remove from it  . Now going by the logic of the answer in the post that I linked to we are actually passing a copy of the reference of `foo` to the method `put()` right ?In that case putting the `foo` into the `HashMap` shouldn't prevent it from getting garbage collected . Can you please help me understand what is going on here ? What am I missing exactly ?

```
 public void someMethod(){
     Foo foo  = new Foo();
     somehashMap.put(fooKey,foo); 
  }
```

Comment: `Foo` will have the same lifetime as `somehashMap`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Garbage collection isn't applicable to references but to *actual* objects which reside in heap. When you put `foo` in the `Map`, you are basically helping it "escape" out of its current scope and putting it in the same scope/life-time as `somehashMap`.

References in Java are handled transparently behind the scenes. When you put the `foo` reference in the map, a copy of the *reference* is actually passed to the `put` method call but the underlying object i.e. `new Foo()` is the same for both the original and the copied references. Let's look at the below snippet:

```
public void doIt() {
  Object f1 = new Object();
  Object f2 = f1;
  Object f3 = f2;
}
```

In the above snippet, how many objects are garbage collected after execution of `doIt` completes? It's just the single `new Object()` which we created. Rest all are simply references or aliases which are used to point to the same object.

Answer (score 7):

An object can't be garbage collected as long as it is reachable. In your case, foo can be reached by `Foo foo = someHashMap.get(fooKey);` so can't be garbage collected as long as it is in the map and the map itself is reachable.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you're clear on what a reference actually is.

You're partially right that 'foo' is a reference to an object, and adding it to the hashmap effectively creates a second reference to the same object.

However, that's exactly why the object isn't going to get garbage-collected when your 'foo' variable disappears. Objects are garbage-collected only when there are no references left - you start out with one reference (foo), then create a second (inside the hashmap), the first reference vanishes when your function ends, but you still have one reference left.

Answer (score 6):

Try a picture:

[image]

Boxes are objects. Unboxed letters are variables.

At the start you just have your hashmap, which I'm assuming exists before your function is called, and continues existing afterwards.

Then `new Foo()` creates a new object, and `f=` creates a variable which refers to it.

Then `hashmap.put(k,f)` creates an entry in the hashmap, which points to the same object as f does.

Then when you exit the function, the local variable `f` ceases to exist, but everything else remains.

The Garbage Collector won't remove the Foo object, because the hashmap still points to it. And that's what you want -- if you later call `hashmap.get(k)`, you would expect to get that Foo object.

If you remove the entry from the hashmap - `hashmap.remove(k)` then the Foo object can be garbage-collected.

If the hashmap itself stops existing, then the Foo object can be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 3):

Most languages with garbage collector support some kinds of [weak references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference). You can find a weak hash map implementation in Java, for example. If you put a foo object into the weak hash map and garbage collector will run then the foo object will be collected and removed from the weak hash map if no other pointers to foo exists (except week pointers). Sometimes you can escape memory leaks this way.

Answer (score 2):

As long as foo is in the HashMap it can not be garbage collected, because Java does not know you will never use it again. foo can be garbage collected as soon as *all* references are end-of-life.

Answer (score 2):

> we are actually passing a copy of the reference of foo to the method
>   put() right?

**Yes**,  Java is passing a copy of the reference which intern map hold `reference` to the`same object` in memory (`heap`) so it will not be eligible for GC until your map.

Answer (score 1):

The pass by value in the case of this `put` method is the value of the reference to `foo`. Since `foo` is reference counted, as long as `somehashMap` holds the reference, `foo` won't get garbage collected.

I did find a memory leak like this in some code that I inherited where someone was using the map to cache images but when the image was needed again, instead of grabbing the cached image, a new one was created anyway and pushed into the map with a new key.

Answer (score 1):

Java passes by value indeed. However you are passing a *reference* by value, not an *instance* of an object.