# What does the object creation statement in java exactly means?

Tags: java

Assuming X and Y both class.What does below statements means?

```
X obj1 = new X();
X obj2 = new Y();
```

Whose reference and whose memori will be given in above case? please elaborate!

Answer (score 2):

This creates an object of type `X` and assigns a reference to it to a variable called `obj1`.

It then creates another object, this time of of type `Y`, and assigns a reference to it to a variable called `obj2`.

For the second line to compile, `Y` has to be a subclass of `X`.

Comment: I still didn't get you...What does object of type Y means in sense of memory and reference?

Comment: @Niyatpatel: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-is-a-class-reference-and-an-object?

Answer (score 0):

`X` is just a handler. The actual object creation is defined by the `new` statement. 
So

```
X obj1 = new X();  // ---> Will create an X() object 
X obj2 = new Y();  // ---> Will create an Y() object
```

In each case they reference a separate location in the memory. 
In other words, `obj1 != obj2`