# Java TreeMap get method

Tags: java, methods, get, key, treemap

When i use the `V get(Object key)` method in a Java `TreeMap<K, V>` I obtain a brand new copy of the value connected to the key I insert in the `V get(Object key)` method, or I got a "reference" to the value V right inside the `TreeMap`?

Comment: The value _is_ the reference.

Comment: A bit of a shameless plug, but if the difference between a reference and an object confuses you, maybe check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-is-a-class-reference-and-an-object.

Comment: The whole problem was if the get method would gave me the object inside the TreeMap or a new object not in the TreeMap :-) Problem solved below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Map#get()` returns a *reference* but the `Map#put()` method too stores a *reference* only. The actual `Object` lives on the *heap*. In fact, the `TreeMap` works with `Entry<K,V>` references and the actual `Entry` objects on the *heap* then point to the actual *key* and *value* objects on the *heap* again.

Comment: So with the get method I'll be able to modify the very object I put in before?

Answer (score 1):

In general, Java's standard collections do not copy the values they are given. If you notice, the values are not constrained to be `Cloneable` (and even if they were, because of the weirdness of `Cloneable`, it wouldn't ensure that they were actually clonable). And there is no other way for a copy to be created (since you cannot run `new` on a generic type variable).

Therefore, they have to make do with the references they were given, and that's what you get when you retrieve them with `get()`.