# Methods and declaration java

Tags: java, variables, methods, declaration

I am trying to make an program to determine averages for school. I am going to have all the files saved to the computer so its easy to access them for multiple uses. I stated to create multiple methods and discovered a problem. I have the user input for a subject in the *startup* method but in the *main* method, *sub* (the subject string) is used and its says "sub cannot be resolved to a variable" I understand why it say this but I am unsure how to fix.
Here is my code:

```
public class Calculator {
static int x;
static int b;


public static void startup() {
    System.out.println("**Receiving User**");
    String user = System.getProperty("user.home");
    System.out.println("**Checking Directories**");
    boolean dir = new File(user + "/Library/Application Support/Average_Calculator/Settings/").mkdirs();
    if (dir) {
        System.out.println("**Directory Created at:" + user + "/Library/Application Support/Average_Calculator/**");
    } else {
        System.out.println("**Directory Has Already Been Created at:" + user
                + "/Library/Application Support/Average_Calculator/**");
    }
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Average Calculator");
    System.out.println("Please input the subject average you want to calculate(no caps)");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sub = scan.nextLine();
    // System.out.println(sub);
    try {
        // System.out.println("It Does!");
        FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(
                user + "/Library/Application Support/Average_Calculator/" + sub + ".sav");
        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        FileOutputStream SetsaveFile = new FileOutputStream(
                user + "/Library/Application Support/Average_Calculator/Settings/" + "Setting" + sub + ".sav");
        ObjectOutputStream setsave = new ObjectOutputStream(SetsaveFile);
        // Create an ObjectOutputStream to put objects into save file.

        // Close the file.
        save.close();
        setsave.close();// This also closes saveFile.
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace(); // If there was an error, print the info.
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    startup();
    System.out.println(sub);
    try {
        // Open file to read from, named SavedObj.sav.
        FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream(sub + ".sav");

        // Create an ObjectInputStream to get objects from save file.
        ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);

        x = (Integer) save.readObject();
        b = (Integer) save.readObject();

        // Close the file.
        save.close(); // This also closes saveFile.
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // exc.printStackTrace(); // If there was an error, print the info.
    }

    // Print the values, to see that they've been recovered.
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(b);

    // All done.
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!
PS I am new to methods and classes, an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sub` is currently a local variable of `startup()`, so `main()` does not have access to it.

One solution is to have `startup()` return the value of `sub`, and to have `main()` use that returned value.

A second solution would be to declare `sub` (and any other shared variables) as a `static` variable of the `Calculator` class, which would place it within the scope of both static methods. In this case, you must no longer declare `sub` locally within `startup()`, since that would cause the method to ignore the static variable with the same name.

Comment: At the end of startup i put return sub; but it still say "sub can't be resolved to a variable"

Comment: `main()` now has to use the returned value! Try changing the statement that calls `startup()` to `String sub = startup();`. I have updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you it works now one last question can I have startup return multiple  Strings because I need to do the same thing as I did to sub as to user

Comment: The issue with that is I need the user input in startup and by doing what you said I can't do that anymore. Thanks for helping me

Comment: No, with the second solution, `startup()` can still *use* `sub` -- it just must not *declare* it (since that would cause the method to ignore the `static` variable with the same name). In other words, `String sub = scan.nextLine();` would simply need to be changed to `sub = scan.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring sub in your startup method but trying to access it in your main method. The scope of variables declared in methods is limited to that method; that means that once you leave the method, the variable is no longer accessible. If you want to access a variable both methods one option is to make it a property of the class like you did for x and b. Another option is to return the value of sub at the end of your startup method then simply print your call to the method in main.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-is-a-class-reference-and-an-object) is a good explanation about classes.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function) is a good explanation about methods (you can ignore the part about functions; the explanation for methods is still good).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at those

Answer (score 0):

Your startup function is returning a void.  Change this line:

```
public static void startup() {
```

to this:

```
public static String startup() {
```

and this line:

```
startup();
```

to this:

```
String sub = startup();
```

Comment: Thanks fixed the first problem but now next to my startup method it says "This method must return a result of type String"

Comment: Now add  return sub as the last line of the startup() method and you should be good to go.