# python call methods from super class

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to understand python inheritance a little.  Here is a use case:

```
class Test:

    def hello():
        print("hello")
        return "hello"

    def hi():
        print(hello())
        print("HI")

class Test1(Test):
    hi()
    pass

x = Test1()
x.hello()
```

I don't understand why I can't call "hi()" in class Test1.  It inherited it class Test right?

Comment: Because that's not how you call methods inside classes. What are you attempting to do by writing that call at the class level?

Comment: Well, I figure since Test1 inherits Test, it should be able to call it at class level right?

Comment: I think what you wanted to do is to call `hi()` from the object `x`. (e.g. after `x.hello()` call `x.hi()` and it will work as expected)

Comment: @ozn no. Why would you think that?

Comment: I want to call "hi()" from Test1 class, not necessarily create an object.

Comment: Then you are not using classes in any understandable way. Classes are *for* creating objects. You need to explain *why* you would want to do something different.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Well thats what I am trying to understand.  is this valid?

Comment: @ozn I have posted an answer with some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the relationship and definitions of `class`es and `object`s. *Classes are like blueprints to create objects*. By writing methods inside a class, you are essentially defining the behaviors of the object that can be created from the class blueprint. So, with your code:

```
class Test:

    def hello():
        print("Hello")
        return "Hello"

    def hi():
        print(hello())
        print("Hi")


class Test1(Test):

    hi() # <- You really shouldn't call a method directly from a "blueprint" class
    pass

x = Test1()
x.hello()
```

While your last two lines of code are valid, it's a bad idea (and almost always invalid) to call a method outside of the class's scope directly inside a class definition. The reason why `hi()` does not work in the `Test1` class is that it's not defined in the scope of `Test1`; even though this class indeed inherits from the `Test` class, it *only affects the object that is created from the class* (like the object `x` you created from the `Test1()` class).

Here's a more detailed explanation about classes and objects from another relevant question: [What are classes, references and objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-are-classes-references-and-objects)

Hope this helped!