# Is Runnable an interface or an object in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, instantiation, runnable

While creating threads I see code like:-

```
Runnable watdaheck = new Runnable()
{
System.out.println("java with time contradicts itself");
}
```

From what I know an interface cannot be instantiated so I fail to understand how we can write Runnable() for creating anonymous class. An interface can be given a reference but cannot be instantiated is what we are taught in polymorphism.

Comment: Note that the thing that's like an interface but that you can instantiate is a _class_, not an object. I think you meant to ask if Runnable is an interface or a class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-are-classes-references-and-objects/9224971) for more.

Answer (score 6):

`Runnable` is interface, you are creating an [*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which implements the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface.

Answer (score 2):

I just modify a bit your code.

```
 Runnable watdaheck = new Runnable()
    {    
         public void run(){
             System.out.println("java with time contradicts itself");
         }
    }
```

The right part

```
new Runnable()
    {    
         public void run(){
             System.out.println("java with time contradicts itself");
         }
    }
```

is an instance of an `anonymous class` that implements interface `Runnable`
The left part `Runnable watdaheck`, `watdaheck` is a reference that refers to above object.
Your code is same with below code:

```
class SubRunnable implements Runnable{
   public void run(){
       //do something
   }
}
Runnable r = new SubRunnable();
```

You should read more about anonymous class in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Runnable is an interface. We use it with the "new" operator in order to create an anonymous class object whICH