# I don't understand how Node.next works

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, reference, singly-linked-list

I'm, learning how linked list works but i can't understand some simple stuff like how Node.next work, i think the problem is that i don't understand how reference in java works.

```
public class Node {
int date;
Node next; //This line i don't understand, what are we doing when we declare  class type inside the same class
}
```

but there is also:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
private Node first; //What is the difference between this line and the line in the class Node?
```

Comment: What *do* you understand about object references in Java? It's kinda hard to fill in the blanks if you don't tell us where they are ...

Comment: (is this about Java syntax or the concept of object references in general?)

Answer (score 1):

```
Node next;
```

Is what you could call a *forward* reference. It tells you that an instance of that class `Node` has a **reference** that **can** point to *another* Node instance.

Initially of course, that reference will be null (not pointing to another `Node`). But when you start building your list of nodes, that works by one Node ... linking to the `next` Node, by changing that field value from null, to point to some instance of that class. That is how simple linked lists work: you start with a single root node, and adding notes to the list means: updating such `next` fields.

From that point of view, there is no "real" difference between the two classes above. You could as well go:

```
Node firstNode = new Node(5);
Node secondNode = new Node(42);
firstNode.next = secondNode;
```

The main point of having a distinct class with a `first` field is for conceptual reasons: that second class "tells" the reader: "my purpose is to contain the first Node object of a list".

You can turn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-are-classes-references-and-objects) for more extensive explanations about classes, objects, and references.

And note: the really crucial point here is that, by default, when you do a `new Node()` call, that field `next` starts of with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you creating an object(in this case Node)and that is important for you what is next object (or previous or parent or child ,etc)  to point that object you need a variable with type of same object.