# what is the difference between p->next = q and p=q where p & q both are pointers to a struct

Tags: data-structures, merge, linked-list

I am trying to merge two linked lists.
It works correctly when I write this:

```
if(p->data < q->data){
                third = p;
                last = p;
                p = p->next;
                third->next = NULL;
        }else{
                third = q;
                last = q;
                q = q->next;
                third->next = NULL;
        }
```

But it doesn't work correctly when I write this:

```
if(p->data < q->data){
                third = p;
                last = p;
                third->next = NULL;
                p = p->next;
        }else{
                third = q;
                last = q;
                third->next = NULL;
                q = q->next;
        }
```

I am wondering why. Can anyone explain?
third: Pointer from where merged list starts.
p, q: Pointers to 2 lists.
last: Pointer which connects further elements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-are-classes-references-and-objects. It is about Java but the principles there are the same as what's confusing you. You're overwriting `p->next` when you say `third->next = NULL;` in the second example, which is why it's not working. `third` and `p` point to the same location in memory.

Comment: So what happens to third when I say p = p->next?

Comment: Nothing. `p` and `third` are different variables that point to the same location memory. When you overwrite `p` with `p->next`, `third` doesn't change.

Comment: Then why does it matter if I do third->next=NULL before p=p->next?

Comment: Because `third` and `p` point to the same object, so `third->next` and `p->next` are the same thing, until you execute `p=p->next`.

Comment: Does that mean code is seperating whatever third is pointing at?

Comment: I don't understand the question.