# Same thing like C++ pointer in Java

Tags: java, c++, pointers

Is there anything similar to C++ pointers in Java? If there is, I would like to know what it is. Could you give me some examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629357/does-java-have-pointers

Comment: No, what exactly do you want to achieve!

Comment: Java does not have pointers. Use polymorphism

Comment: @close-voters: you're wrong. asking whether Java has "pointers" (*yes*, the Java language specification says so) is very different from asking whether has "same thing like C++ pointer (*no*, it doesn't). Get a grip. The answers are directly **opposite**, it's no duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's pointers (so called by the language specification, while I believe Java programmers mostly know them as "references") do not support *pointer arithmetic*.

And Java has no way to do pointer arithmetic.

If you want to do such low-level stuff in Java, one way is to use JNI (the Java Native Interface) to access code written in C or C++.

Answer (score 3):

The Java object model is different from that of C++:

- In C++, for every *type* you can have a variable of that type. Additionally, for every non-reference type `T` there is a type `T&` and you can have variables of that type (but references are never objects).
- In Java, types which are class types can never be the type of a variable. Objects of class type can *only* exist dynamically, and a variable that is declared as being of type `T` (where `T` is of class type) is always implicitly a *tracked reference* to an object. (Let us ignore primitive types for this discussion.)

In both languages, variables are scoped. However, in C++ you can take advantage of scoped lifetime because objects whose lifetime ends automatically call a destructor. In Java, the only variables are references, and their going out of scope does something very different: It informs the memory manager that the object which they were tracking now has one fewer reference; and if there are no based references left, the object becomes eligible for (non-deterministic) collection.

If you will, you can equate class-type variables in Java to pointers in C++:

```
// Java:
{
    Foo x = new Foo();
    x = new Foo();      // no assignment in Java!
}

// C++:
{
    Foo * px = new Foo;
    px = new Foo;       // ... leaks the previous object
}
```