# Char pointers in Java

Tags: java, pointers

Is it possible to point to the first element of a char[] in java?

I have this code in C++ as an example of what I am trying to do:

```
char word[100] = " ";
char *p;

cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin.getline(word, 100);

p = word + strlen(word) - 1;
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Java?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Java has no pointers. Just object references

Comment: Java has pointers in the sense of variables that store references to data in memory. All variables of Object types in Java are pointers in this sense. However, the Java language does not allow arithmetic operations on the values of pointers, like you'd be able to do in a language like C. Source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629357/does-java-have-pointers

Comment: Dean, can you maybe clarify what you need a pointer for... The snippet above would be functionally the same if `p` was of the type `char` and you just the assign first element to `p`

Answer (score 2):

Java lacks the concept of pointers, so the answer is "no". All operations on an array must be performed using indexes.

The consequence of this is that you cannot pass a single argument so methods expecting to read or write arrays starting at a certain position; you always need an array and an index.

**Note:** In general, C++ approaches to reading strings do not translate to Java very well, because Java I/O libraries will manage memory for you, freeing you from having to worry about buffer overruns on reading a string.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no concept of pointers **and** Java `String`(s) have a fixed length (they're also *immutable* so they have a **fixed *everything***).

That being said, your posted code is reading one word which you could do with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = scan.next(); // <-- nextLine() if you want a line.
int length = word.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept of pointers are not used in java reason been that  memory release and  allocation is done automatically by the java virtual machine , the only way to access an array reference is through the index

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: No... Java does not have any pointers. It only has Object **references**. Any non-primitive data type is pass-by-reference, meaning that if you have the following:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a;
Object c = new Object();
```

`a == b` is true, while `b == c` and `a == c` are false.

If you want to have pointer-like behavior in Java, you need to wrap it up in an Object and use references. For example, it is possible that an `AtomicInteger[]` could be used, and you pass a reference to one of the `AtomicInteger`s, but it would probably be best to hold the `int` index as a 'pointer' to the location in the array. Furthermore, your snippet of code *could* just have a `char` variable, set to `word[0]`. It really depends on what you need a pointer for...